# socket.io and node callback functions not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, socket.io

I'm having a really difficult time grasping asynchronous callbacks and variable storage in socket.io. I want the code in the callback function to be executed after all the queries are made. However, I don't know where to place the callback() method call so it executes after everything is finished. I would greatly appreciate any and all help.

```
//The code below queries a database and stores the information in a json object.
var mysql = require('mysql')
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000)
    var db = mysql.createConnection({     
        host: '',
        user: '',
        password: '',
        database: '',
        port: 3306,
    })
    db.connect(function(err){
        if (err) console.log(err)
    })

console.log(1);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
   socket.on('key', function(value){//client side has a onclick() function that emits 'key'
        console.log(2);
        var total = {};
        var personalTable = []
        var liwcTable = []
        var id = value;

        help(total, function(total) {
            console.log(4);
            console.log("total = " + JSON.stringify(total));
            socket.emit('total', total);/emits to client
        });

        function help(total, callback) {
            console.log(3);
            db.query('SELECT * FROM `a` WHERE `userId` =' + id)
                .on('result', function(data){
                    liwcTable.push(data)
                })
                .on('end', function(){
                    total["initial liwcTable"] = liwcTable;
                })
            db.query('SELECT * FROM `b`  WHERE `userId` =' + id)
                .on('result', function(data){
                    personalTable.push(data)
                })
                .on('end', function(){
                    total['personalTable'] = personalTable;
                }) 
            callback(total)//needs to be executed after the queries are done.
         }
    })    
})
```

The code goes into the callback method before the queries have a chance to finish. I also don't understand how I can be updating my json object "total" when the scope of the query callbacks are limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many solutions to trigger a callback after all wanted actions.
You can for example, create a singleton called after each query, which will trigger the final callback.

```
function help(total, callback) {

    var nbEndedQueries = 0,
        amountOfQueries = 2;//nb of linked queries
    function singleton() {

        //increments the nbEndedQueries variable and tests if the max is reached
        if(++nbEndedQueries >= amountOfQueries)
            callback();
    }


    db.query(... //query calling)
        .on('result', ...//some behaviours
            singleton();
        )
    db.query(... //query calling)
        .on('result', ...//some behaviours
            singleton();
        )
    //...

}
```

An other solution is to use the promises.
Many modules like Q or the ECMA6 polyfill provide you this feature which is totaly awesome

sample with ecm6 promise polyfill

```
//promisification of the query method
function query(string) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        db.query(string)
            .on('result', resolve)
            //i supposed an error event exist
            .on('error', reject);

    })
}

//and now the usage
function help() {

    //basic method
    //first query calling
    query('your query string')
        .then(function(result) {
            //behaviour

            //second query calling, the result will send to the next 'then' statement
            return query('second query');
        })
        .then(function() {
            //behaviour


            //at this point, all queries are finished
            callback() ;
        });
}
```

---

```
//parallelized sample

function help() {

    //starts all queries and trigger the then if all succeeds
    Promise.all([query('your query string'), query('second query')])
        .then(function(results/*array of results*/) {
            //behaviour

            callback();
        })
}
```